# How to build linux command for Android on Linux machine

Tags: android, linux, shell, command-line, build

Since there are a few commands missing on Android, I want to build them by myself.

Take one as an example:

There is no `dig` command on Android.

I've got the source code from `ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.2.3/bind-9.2.3.tar.gz` and then I want to build it. But I got stuck.

How can I build the executable on my `linux machine`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways.

1. To build *any* C Source code for Android Platform you can use **Android NDK Toolchian**, It lets you build *Native* code for another platform.
   It can be used as a [stand-alone](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html) compiler without an Android APK.
   [Documentation](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/OVERVIEW.html) and [Sample Code](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Samples).

   To build it as an executable (without APK) and not shared object, replace `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` with `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)` in `Android.mk`.
2. For Linux commands on Android you can use [Busybox](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-busybox/).
   It supports most of the commands.
   However `dig` is not supported in busybox, you can add it by following this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-busybox/#N10226).

Hopefully this gives you a start.